# The gradient vector in Hamiltonian Monte Carlo (leapfrog method)

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

Let $x_{t}, \omega_{t} \in \mathbb{R^{d}}$
The Hamiltonian Monte Carlo says this:

1. **Deterministic**: it relies on the Hamiltonian dynamics so given an initial state, at any time $t$, specified by the position and momentum $(x_{t}, \omega_{t})$, the state $(x_{T}, \omega_{T})$, of the system at a forward time $T$ can be determined.
   The Hamiltonian can be computed like $H(x_{t}, \omega_{t}) = -log(\pi(x_{t})) + V(\omega_{t}) = U(x_{t}) + V(\omega_{t})$
2. **Randomness**: the initial momentum $\omega_{0}$ is sampled from a multi-variate Gaussian pdf. By the Hamiltonian dynamics, the position $x_{t}, \forall t > 0$ is determined by the momentum $\omega_{0}$.

**Note**: The target distribution is $\pi(x_{t})$ but can be approximated by a proposal distribution $r(x_{t})$ such that $r(x_{t}) \propto \pi(x_{t})$

Here's the pseudo - code:

Let $\epsilon L = T$ where $\epsilon$ is the step size in the discretisation and $L$ is the number of updates in the dynamics.

1. Generate the initial momentum $\omega_{0} ~ N(0, M^{-1})$ where $M$ is a diagonal matrix like $M = diag(m_{1}, ..., m_{d}): m_{1} = ... = m_{d}$
2. set $x^{0} = x_{0}$
3. for the momentum: make a half - step update: $w^{(0)} = \omega_{0} - \frac{\epsilon}{2}\nabla log[r(x^{0})]$
4. For $l = 1, 2,..., L$:

4.1 update position: $x^{(l)} = x^{(l-1)} + \epsilon .\omega^{(l-1)}$

4.2 update momentum: $\omega^{(l)} = \omega ^{(l-1)} -\epsilon . \nabla log[r(x^{t})]$

**Few questions:**

1. What does *set $x^{(0)}$ = $x_{0}$* means? Are we suppose to assign a value $x_{0}$ to a variable (declaring a variable) or are we instantiating a variable (variable is created but does not references a value)? How do we determine the value of $x_{0}$ to initialise if by declaration?
2. How is the proposal distribution $r(x_{t})$ approximated?
3. *for the momentum: make a half - step update: $w^{(0)} = \omega_{0} - \frac{\epsilon}{2}\nabla log[r(x^{0})]$*.
   $x_{0}$ is a scalar value or a vector of scalar values for $d > 1$ so if $r(x_{t})$ is a distribution function, then the outcome is also scalar (or a vector of scalars). The action of the gradient operator on $log[r(x^{0})]$ yields $0$ in each direction $d$.
   This appears to be rather odd as this returns $w^{(0)}$ = $\omega_{0}$
4. *update momentum: $\omega^{(l)} = \omega ^{(l-1)} -\epsilon . \nabla log[r(x^{t})]$*. $\nabla log[r(x^{t})] = \vec{0}$ (or 0, if $d = 1$) which means $\omega^{l} = \omega^{(l-1)}$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not true that $\nabla\log r(x)=0$ in all directions. If it were true, $r(x)$ would be constant.  [The first Bartlett identity looks a bit like this, but (a) it's an expectation and (b) the derivative is wrt a parameter rather than the random variable $x$]

Comment: @ThomasLumley Let's suppose $d=1$ for the simplest case: $r(x)$ is a scalar, isn't it? The log of this is a scalar and the derivative of this is a scalar, isn't it?

What am I missing?

Comment: @ThomasLumley Looking at other sources, I suspect the pseudo - code is implying that we take the functional form for $r(x)$, rather than the output of $r(x)$

Comment: Try a standard Normal: $log r(x)= -x^2/2+\text{constants}$. The derivative is $-x$, which typically isn't zero

Comment: @ThomasLumley Yes, this was exactly my point above. The derivative of the pdf is taken rather than the probability of a random variable X.